# How to outputs the first row with a matching key in Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a **data.txt** text file as below.

```
0000007 aaa 20060201 117
0000007 aaa 20060202 136
0000007 aaa 20060203 221
0000017 bbbb 20060201 31
0000017 bbbb 20060202 127
0000017 bbbb 20060203 514
0000021 ccccc 20060201 900
0000021 ccccc 20060202 324
0000021 ccccc 20060203 129
```

Exp1: Now, I want to outputs the first row with a matching key of column(1) and column(2). 
what should I do?

```
I want to have the desired output result as below.
```

```
0000007 aaa 20060201 117
0000017 bbbb 20060201 31
0000021 ccccc 20060201 900
```

Exp2: Same as above, I also want to outputs the first rows with a matching key of column(1) and column(3). what should I do?

```
I want to have the desired output result as below.
```

```
0000007 aaa 20060201 117
0000007 aaa 20060203 136
0000017 bbbb 20060201 31
0000017 bbbb 20060203 127
0000021 ccccc 20060201 900
0000021 ccccc 20060202 324
0000021 ccccc 20060201 129
```

This is my code:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/data.txt") 
val keyed = lines.map(line => line.split(" ")(0) -> line) 
val deduplicated = keyed.reduceByKey((a, b) => a)
deduplicated.values.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is being tagged as "unclear what you are asking". What are the parameters to your function? What is the key you are trying to match? Please have a read through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is my code:
````
val lines = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/data1.txt")
val keyed = lines.map(line => line.split(" ")(0) -> line)
val deduplicated = keyed.reduceByKey((a, b) => a)
deduplicated.values.foreach(println)
````

Comment: Please modify your question with the code instead of putting it in a comment. Also write what you are inputting, what you get as output and what you wanted to get as output.

Comment: OK, I done it. Please help me, expert.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Spark you are using - from the code you have posted it looks like you are using the old RDD-API, in which case you almost there. You just need to add both keys - either (col1, col2) or (col1, col3) -  and then call `collect` before you print:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/data.txt") 
val keyed = lines.map(line => {
  val cols = line.split(" ")
  // 1. scenario 
  ((cols(0), cols(1)), (cols(2), cols(3)))
  // 2. scenario 
  //((cols(0), cols(2)), (cols(1), cols(3)))
})

val deduplicated = keyed
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a)

deduplicated.values.collect foreach println // add collect
```

Without the `collect` your data will be printed to stdout at the different workers, and you don't see the output on the driver. Note that `collect` should be used with care (usually in debugging mode only) as it collects all data from the workers to the driver. If you have a large data set, your driver will die with an OOM-exception.

As a side note, I would generally recommend that you move from the old RDD-API to either the Dataframe-API or the Dataset-API, but there may of course be reasons why you have not made the shift...

Comment: @JohnTrung Did it work? If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: If I convert text file to DataFrame, I want to output the rows but the exclude first row. what should I do?
I want to have the desired output result as below.
    +-------+-----+--------+------+
    |   key |value|  value2|value3| 
    +-------+-----+--------+------+
    |0000007|  aaa|20060202|   136| 
    |0000007|  aaa|20060203|   221| 
    |0000017| bbbb|20060202|   127| 
    |0000017| bbbb|20060203|   514| 
    |0000021|ccccc|20060202|   324| 
    |0000021|ccccc|20060203|   129| 
    +-------+-----+--------+------+

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
//Extract first row 
val lastMatchRes = myDataAsDataFrame.groupBy($"key", $"value").agg(first($"value2"), first($"value3")) 
//Output the rows but the exclude first row 
val data = myDataAsDataFrame.filter(x => x != lastMatchRes).show
````

Comment: Okay, so from the filename you use ("/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3...") it looks like you are using Spark version 2+? In that case, I would suggest you abandon the RDD api and switch to the Dataframe api. Also use `spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", " ").csv("/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/data.txt")` instead of `sc.textFile(..)`. Using `option("header", "true")` will interpret the first line as column names.